# Add description with node name in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, label, networkx

I'm trying to add description/text with node name.

For example :

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

Above code will give me with this graph with node name as labels.

[image: Default Labels]

If I use custom labels :

```
labels = {}
labels[1] = 'First Node'
labels[2] = 'Second Node'
labels[3] = 'Third Node'
nx.draw(G,labels=labels,with_labels=True)
```

I get this graph:
[image: Custom Label]

I am working on graph problem and for debugging purpose I need to attach information with each node along with node name. But when I'm attaching that I'm unable to get name and if I attach extra text then I'm unable to get node names.

How can I add both on node not on edge?

Comment: What is your desired output for your custom labels? Something like `nodename: label_text`, e.g. "1: FirstNode" in your example?

Comment: yes, I want node name inside circle and with that to add text near it. That text is information return by child to this node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can plot the node ids and additional information:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 3)

# get positions
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)

# shift position a little bit
shift = [0.1, 0]
shifted_pos ={node: node_pos + shift for node, node_pos in pos.items()}

# Just some text to print in addition to node ids
labels = {}
labels[1] = 'First Node'
labels[2] = 'Second Node'
labels[3] = 'Third Node'
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, shifted_pos, labels=labels, horizontalalignment="left")

# adjust frame to avoid cutting text, may need to adjust the value
axis = pl.gca()
axis.set_xlim([1.5*x for x in axis.get_xlim()])
axis.set_ylim([1.5*y for y in axis.get_ylim()])
# turn off frame
pl.axis("off")

pl.show()
```

Result

[image: Figure with Labels and Node Id]